# How to keep another user logged in?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

All users have encrypted home folders on one server I maintain and one of the users (non-human account) has useful resources in its home directory shared via Apache.

In order to keep the user's home folder mounted, somebody will have to log in as that user. I achieve this by logging into that server using SSH and `su` that user. However, sometimes I forgot about that and logs out or closes the ssh client and other uses lose access to those files.

I am just wondering is there any command I can run to keep that user logged in?

I tried `screen`, but it does not work in `su` via ssh:

```
$ screen
Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/0' - please check.
```

I have also tried `disown` and `nohup`'ing `cat <> /dev/zero` but the process is still terminated after I log out.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What ssh client? Connected to where? Why exactly does the user need to be logged in? Can't you run whatever you need through `cron`? Could you show the actuall commands you need to run to make the files accessible?

Comment: I have updated the question. There's no special command to access those files, but the encrypted home folder is only mounted when the user is logged in. I cannot use `cron` or any automated solution because the password cannot be stored on that machine.

Comment: OK, so the user's home is mounted through autofs or similar? Is changing the way it is mounted an option? Why do you only mount the folder if the user is logged in? Anyway, `nohup cat /dev/zero > /dev/null &` allows me to exit my ssh session without stopping the process.

Comment: It's just the standard Ubuntu encrypted file system (ecryptfs). Apart from this log in issue, it has proven to be very reliable and maintainable. I tried your nohup and it worked so my previous way must be wrong. However, CPU usage of that `cat` is 100%, so `/dev/zero` does not seems to be a very good input for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`screen` works if you chown your current TTY to the target user, before `su`ing to them.

But a better option would be to **mount the home directory manually, using `mount -t ecryptfs`**.

(You could also cheat by incrementing the refcount in `/dev/shm/ecryptfs-<user>`, so that it would never reach 0.)

Comment: I have tried incrementing `/dev/shm/ecryptfs-<user>` and it worked. Thanks! I will look into how to mount ecryptfs at some point I think.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your old `nohup` failed is because you did not send it to the background. If all you need is any random process that remains even after you log out, try something like this:

```
nohup sh -c 'while true; do sleep 60; done' &
```

I do agree with @grawity that if you are better off changing the way you mount the directory.